# Swift - determine which button was pressed with switch

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have 4 buttons that call one function. Depending on which button was pressed i need to hide button inside of function that called after pressing.I dont know which button was pressed so i tried to assign tags for each of 4 buttons to identify them by tag and use switch

I tried this

```
            switch sender.tag {
            case 1:
                self.button1.hidden = true
            case 2:
                self.button2.hidden = true
            case 3:
                self.button3.hidden = true
            case 4:
                self.button4.hidden = true

            }
```

but this doesnt work compiler says about use of unresolved identifier 'sender'

How to do this correctly ?

EDIT:

Whole function

```
  if self.allowMistakeVar {

        let mistakeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Here is title!", message: "message of alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { UIAlertAction in

            self.allowMistakeVar = false
            self.allowMistakeButton.enabled = false


            switch sender.tag {
            case answer1Text:
                self.answer1Text.hidden = true
            case answer2Text:
                self.answer2Text.hidden = true
            case answer3Text:
                self.answer3Text.hidden = true
            case answer4Text:
                self.answer4Text.hidden = true

            }

        }

        mistakeAlert.addAction(okay)
        self.presentViewController(mistakeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil )

    } else {
```

another case..
}

Comment: How do you do to call the function from the 4 buttons ?

Comment: please show your whole function where you have put this code.

Comment: @Er. Kukadiya updatet post

Comment: @Poql  
after the button is pressed I check if the title is equal to variable A. if no, i call function inside which i check if another variable B is true or false and if true i need to hide button which was pressed

Comment: @Poql also updated the question with whole function

Comment: I don't really got it. But you should use addTarget: of your UIButtons to specify which function to call. Then use tags to know which button called the function.

Comment: Why you always want to use tags to determine the UIButton ? If the called function has a sender parameter, than you know the UIButton which called the function through this parameter

Comment: @JulianM: Your comment is the solution. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

1) Assign tag for each button

```
Button1.tag=1
Button2.tag=2
Button3.tag=3
Button4.tag=4
```

2) Then check your common button action

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
   switch sender.tag {
   case 1: self.sender.hidden = true //button1
           break;
   case 2: self.sender.hidden = true //button2
           break;
   case 3: self.sender.hidden = true //button3
           break;
   case 4: self.sender.hidden = true //button4
           break;
   default: ()
           break;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Why you always want to use tags to determine the UIButton ? If the called function has a sender parameter then you know the UIButton which called the function through this parameter.

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
   switch sender {
   case button1: // Do something
   case button2: // Do some other stuff
   ...
   default: ()
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this could solve the problem because of the error message he got. But thanks. I learnt something.

Answer (score 4):

Put your code in like below as i shown:

```
func btnSomeButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
let tag = sender.tag;
       //put your same code here and either use tag variable as i shown or put as you did.
}
```

--> due to this you will get sender's property easily.

-->Also check that you didn't forgot to give tags to the UIButtons.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but if you set this up in IB, then I would recommend you check if the button was pressed by using the @IBOutlet variables as cases.

```
class SomeView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonC: UIButton!

    @IBAction func didHitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender {
        case buttonA:
            doThis()
        }
        case buttonB:
            doThat()
        }
        case buttonC:
            doThisAgain()
        }
        default:
            doNothing()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you hook up the buttons in your NIB to each @IBOutlet, and all of the buttons to the one @IBAction didHitButton.

This is pretty straight forward, and you don't have to worry about tags or changing names.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using a switch statement you can just use the sender directly.

Note that you need to specify that the sender is a UIButton (therefore this will only work if the function is only called from a button).

```
@IBAction func submitButton(sender: UIButton) {

    /* extra code here */

    sender.enabled = false

}
```

This reduces the code and also allows you to add extra buttons without code changes.