# Am I using a data model properly? How do I organize my code for a filter page?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, filter, uibutton

I am creating a View that is a filter page. The filter page has over 20 buttons for the user to select from. Whatever buttons they select correspond with the images that will be presented to them upon completing their filter selection. (Images are tagged with same buttons as appear on filter page). What I am confused about is how to organize the code for this page. Originally I built the View on the Interface Builder in Main.Storyboard. I created each button individually and hooked them up to the Filter ViewController page associated with the view using IBoutlets and IBactions. This process took a long time and resulted in a very long page of code.

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. I am thinking about programming this page without using the Interface builder and creating arrays that contain the text for various buttons. Does this sound like a good idea? Should the arrays that contain the text for various buttons (organized into categories) be created and stored in a data model or should they be created and stored in the ViewController file? Is this a scenario where using a data model to store the button title Strings, would make sense? I am basing this question off of my developing understanding of the MVC model. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using (or can you use) a table view? It makes creating all those buttons, each with a different title, much easier.

Comment: Haven't been using a tableview since each section on the filter page has a different size horizontal scroll view or no scroll view at all. Will look more into TableViews for this problem though, thanks! @Shades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use a table view, this entire process goes much smoother, and those many lines of code get whittled down to very few lines.

---

Create your table view and have a corresponding `UITableViewController` class

Set up your prototype cell and have a corresponding custom `UITableViewCell` class. Hook up the button to an `IBOutlet` inside that cell class.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

---

**Back to your tableView controller**

Have a variable to hold the titles:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var titles: [String] = []
```

In `viewDidLoad`, get the titles from your data model and fill the `titles` array. If you're doing any processing before you have the finished array, you probably will want a class or struct outside your table view controller which does all the work and sends back only the finished array. In pure MVC, the table view controller should not care *how* the model got that array, only that it returned it. If you simply have an array hardcoded, you can put it right in your view controller code, but as things get more complex, it will be nicer if it's in a different class in a separate file.

In your `cellFoRowAt` method, assign each cell's button with a title from the array which you get with the row's index:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    let title = titles[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.myButton.setTitle("\(title)", for: .normal)
```

---

Now, the great part is that you only have to hook up the one button in Interface Builder to your IBAction. You're going to have to detect which button was pressed (because you now have 20 rows, each with a button that calls the same action.)

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let button = sender   // You now have the exact button that was pressed. You can get the title, get the row number, etc

}
```

Comment: Anyway I could private message you the screen I'm working with and would you be able to let me know if your tableview recommendation would still be ideal?

Comment: @ShaliniSingh There aren’t private message on here. Upload your screenshot to something like imgur, start a chat from here, and share the link. I’ll take a look

Comment: @ShaliniSingh If you need to clean up your code and keep the view controller the way you have it now, you can still have all the buttons connect to one IBAction. Then it’s a matter of having a switch statement to test against the tag or title of the sender (the button that called the IBAction). That at least eliminates the need for 20+ IBActions

Comment: @ShaliniSingh You can keep your layout and use the one IBAction like I mentioned. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985299/swift-determine-which-button-was-pressed-with-switch or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046540/get-button-pressed-id-on-swift-via-sender. They discuss using the tag as a determinant. You can also check the button's title and use that to know which was pressed so you know what action to take

Comment: @ShaliniSingh If your buttons do radically different things and/or a specific button has a lot of code in its action, you probably WANT to give it a separate action so you're not confused as to what that button does.